# Why im getting errors on this?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a new project added a webbrowser.
Then I went to the file App.config.
There were 3-4 lines there and I changed their content to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EnableSqlDependency" value="true" />
    <add key="ApplicationId" value=""></add>
    <YOUR APP="" ID="" GOES="" HERE="">
      " />
      <add key="ApplicationUrl" value="" />
      <add key="ApiKey" value="" />
      <add key="ApplicationSecret" value=""></add><YOUR APP="" SECRET="" GOES="" HERE=""></YOUR>
      " />
      <add key="ExtendedPermissions" value="offline_access" />
    </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I'm getting now 3 errors:

1. Error    1   Application Configuration file "App.config" is invalid. The 'YOUR' start tag on line 6 position 6 does not match the end tag of 'appSettings'. Line 13, position 9.
2. Error    3   Expecting end tag .
3. Error    2   Tag was not closed.

How do i fix this erros ? Can someone show me a fixed code according to my App.config code ?

EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EnableSqlDependency" value="true" />
    <add key="ApplicationId" value=""></add>
    <YOUR APP="" ID="" GOES="" HERE="">
      " />
      <add key="ApplicationUrl" value="" />
      <add key="ApiKey" value="" />
      <add key="ApplicationSecret" value=""></add>
    </YOUR>
      "
      <add key="ExtendedPermissions" value="offline_access" />
    </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Warning 1   The element 'appSettings' has invalid child element 'YOUR'. List of possible elements expected: 'add, remove, clear'.

Comment: Why did you add the line `<YOUR APP="" ID="" GOES="" HERE="">` (several times)?  App.config conforms to a specific template, and that's definitely not part of it.  Just delete those lines and the lines of `" />` below them, and you should be back to functioning.

Comment: @Doron See my answer below. I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

> How do i fix this erros

Remove (or comment) the malformed XML that does not fit the web.config schema:

```
<!-- <YOUR APP="" ID="" GOES="" HERE="">
      " />  -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Config file is mal-formed. Copy below xml and paste-overwrite your current config file.

Then
 - Where it says `YOUR_APP_ID_GOES_HERE` paste the **APP_ID** code you got from the API Provider / whichever API you are trying to use. 
 - Where it says `YOU_APP_SECRET_GOES_HERE` paste the **SECRET CODE / KEY** you got from the API Provider / whichever API you are trying to use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EnableSqlDependency" value="true" />
    <add key="ApplicationId" value="YOUR_APP_ID_GOES_HERE"/>
      <add key="ApplicationUrl" value="" />
      <add key="ApiKey" value="" />
      <add key="ApplicationSecret" value="YOU_APP_SECRET_GOES_HERE" />
      <add key="ExtendedPermissions" value="offline_access" />
    </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Final note: You'll need the `ApiKey` value also set to a valid string, in order to be able to use the API that you are trying to write a client for.